# Не работает sqlite-net-pcl в .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, maui

sqlite-net-pcl работал в Xamarin Forms но после переноса приложения в .Net MAUI при запуске
сборки на эмуляторе оно вылетало при попытке подключения к бд с ошибкой

`System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось нужно установить дополнительный пакет для sqlite.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/dotnet-maui/store-local-data/3-store-data-locally-with-sqlite

Само название пакета SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl.